# Why does dictionary child not get removed in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a structure in Cloud Functions where i go through every child and see if its (endDate) value has passed the current time then delete the child that is expired

all the children of the child node gets deleted except a dictionary child node "coordinate"

why does it not get removed along the rest? how can I do that?

```
exports.removeOldMessages = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const messagesRef = admin.database().ref('events')
    messagesRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            child.forEach((child) => {
                if (Number(child.val()['endDate']) <= new Date().getTime()) {
                   child.ref.set(null)
              }
            })
        })
    })
    return res.status(200).end()
})
```

here is the JSON

```
{   "events" : { "N5iTuYzAbJa02RauxCl3uh2Nggz1" : {  
"-LNmIvSdrwK96KCGcmXm" : {
    "addedBy" : "Riyadh Figures",
    "coordinate" : [ 24.70914690943994, 46.78851541131735 ],
    "endDate" : "1538442801.0",
    "imagePath" : "-LNmIvSdrwK96KCGcmXm",
    "key" : "-LNmIvSdrwK96KCGcmXm",
    "title" : "hjihgf",
    "userPicture" : "N5iTuYzAbJa02RauxCl3uh2Nggz1"   } }
```

Comment: You're definitely not working with promises correctly here.  Also, it seems to me that you could query for only the events to delete (based on the value of endDate) rather than reading every single one of them.  This will run faster and cost you less money.

Answer (score 0):

The `once` function returns a callback, and you are exiting immediately after, so it's probably exiting before even returning the records. Also, `ref.set` returns a promise, and you are not waiting for it, so you also need to wait for it to finish before exiting.

I don't have much experience with Realtime DB, but to wait for the operations to finish this might work:

```
exports.removeOldMessages = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const messagesRef = admin.database().ref('events')
    messagesRef.once('value', (snapshot: DataSnapshot) => {
        let promises = []; // Creates an array to hold the promises
        snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
            snap.forEach((child) => {
                if (Number(child.val()['endDate']) <= new Date().getTime()) {
                   promises.push(child.ref.set(null)) // Add each promise which will then be waited
              }
            })
        })
        Promise.all(promises).then(() => res.status(200).end()); // Wait for all promises to finish before completing
    })
})
```

Comment: i tried the code but now it doesn't remove anything at all. the previous code works and removes all the children except the nested child (coordinate) it doesn't get removed